# How to navigate from item in recylerview to new fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, navigation

Can someone help me figure out how i am supposed to navigate from an item in recyclerview to this repoFragment? I want to display these things in repoFragment using the GitHub API.

I want to click the reponame in the item of the recycler view. With the onClickListener i wish to open a new fragment (RepoFragment) with the info of the clicked item from the recyclerview.

I'm doing a repository search and want to display the info when clicking on the repository.The code below represents what i tried to do.
Thank you for your help!

This is my RepositoryRecyclerAdapter:

```
class RepositoryRecyclerAdapter(repos: List<RepositoriesResponse>): RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchPlaceHolder>(){

private var repoList = repos
var navc: NavController?= null


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SearchPlaceHolder {
    val inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pravokutnik, parent, false);
    return SearchPlaceHolder(inflatedView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchPlaceHolder, position: Int) {
    val repo = repoList[position]
    holder.bindRepo(repo)

   
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View){
            navc?.navigate(R.id.action_searchFragment_to_repoFragment)
            }
        })
    

}

override fun getItemCount() = repoList.size
```

}

This is my SearchFragment:

```
class SearchFragment : BaseFragment<SearchViewModel, FragmentSearchBinding, SearchRepository>() {

private lateinit var mContext: Context
private var reposList = ArrayList<RepositoriesResponse>().toList()
private lateinit var adapterRepo: RepositoryRecyclerAdapter
private lateinit var linearLayoutManagerDistance: LinearLayoutManager




val args: SearchFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mContext = this.requireContext()

    linearLayoutManagerDistance = LinearLayoutManager(mContext)
    linearLayoutManagerDistance.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    binding.repositoriesList.layoutManager = linearLayoutManagerDistance


    

    val query = args.query

    val apiInterface = RepositoryApi.create().getRepositoriesByQuery(query)

    



    apiInterface.enqueue( object : Callback<QueryResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<QueryResponse>?, response: Response<QueryResponse>?) {
            if(response?.body() != null){
                reposList = response.body()!!.items
                adapterRepo = RepositoryRecyclerAdapter(reposList)
                binding.repositoriesList.adapter = adapterRepo

            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<QueryResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    })




}




override fun getViewModel() = SearchViewModel::class.java

override fun getFragmentBinding(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?
) = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

override fun getFragmentRepository()=
    SearchRepository()
```

}

The HomeFragment:

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<HomeViewModel, FragmentHomeBinding, SearchRepository>() {


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    var mySearchView = view.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.search_view)
    var navc = Navigation.findNavController(view)

    mySearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToSearchFragment2(query)
            navc?.navigate(action)
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })

}

override fun getViewModel() = HomeViewModel::class.java

override fun getFragmentBinding(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?
) = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

override fun getFragmentRepository()=
    SearchRepository()
```

}

RepoFragment:

```
class RepoFragment : BaseFragment<RepoViewModel, FragmentRepoBinding, SearchRepository>(){

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_repo, container, false)
}

override fun getViewModel() = RepoViewModel::class.java


override fun getFragmentBinding(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
                                container: ViewGroup?
) = FragmentRepoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


override fun getFragmentRepository() = SearchRepository()
```

}

Also, I get an error when trying to run this code; androidstudio says that i made a mistake when inflating the layout of repofragment.

Comment: Why are you using the FragmentTransaction API to navigate to the Fragment? Why not the Navigation Component. you already seem to be using safe args

Comment: I am confused in how to use it. can you explain?